# Set custom upload form for specific document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to set custom upload form for existing specific document library in sharepoint using visual studio?

Comment: Have you checked out this blogpost? http://byteloom.blogspot.in/2012/01/custom-upload-form-for-document-library.html

Comment: This approach is when we will create document library programmatically. But what we have to do if we want to attach on existing document library?

Answer (score 1):

A custom aspx page would be possible though，but editing the OOTB upload.aspx in the 14 hive would make your environment unsupported, the next time you install an update for sharepoint, your changes could be overwritten.
Modifying any OOTB page will impact all applications running on the same farm. What ever your custom requirement always copy the OOTB  page to a subfolder and try work on that copy.

I'm pretty sure doing this with infopath is not possible, the forms should be bound to a (codebehind) class in the SharePoint object model, which handles the actual upload (add to list, set field values etc. etc.).

Meanwhile, here is one article on custom upload form for your reference.

[Custom upload form for document library in SharePoint 2010 - programmatic approach](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Fx6rkXWdyQQJ:byteloom.blogspot.com/2012/01/custom-upload-form-for-document-library.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&lr=lang_zh-CN%7Clang_en)

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/fb0b5f63-3418-4894-8636-1cff74182546/custom-upload-form-for-a-document-library)

**EDITED:**
Have a look at the below links to

[Modification of '_layouts/upload.aspx'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/modification-of-layouts-upload-aspx)

[Custom upload page in Layouts for document library and it's Navigation from upload menu in the Toolbar. Bend it !! Custom upload menu for the document library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2008/07/18/custom-upload-page-in-layouts-for-document-library-and-it-s-navigation-from-upload-menu-in-the-toolbar-bend-it-custom-upload-menu-for-the-document-library.aspx)

[Manipulate upload link in document library](http://spjsblog.com/2010/06/08/manipulate-upload-link-in-document-library/)

Comment: This approach is when we will create document library programmatically. But what we have to do if we want to attach on existing document library?

Comment: you can user powershell to update default forms of a library like this $web = Get-SPWeb <Url here>
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("<List Here>")
$List.DefaultNewFormUrl = "<new url>
$list.update()