# How customize document upload form for metadata along with document to upload in library?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

My requirement is that-

I have to upload document and some custom column(metadata properties) while uploading document in library. I have to customize document upload form so that can add document metadata property also while uploading document .

Is it possible to customize document upload form using infopath for this?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? If I add additional columns to the document library, after I upload my document I am prompted to enter values into those fields.

Comment: You have to create custom upload form and assign it to doc library. here are similar threads [thread 1](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/modification-of-layouts-upload-aspx). [thread 2](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84395/set-custom-upload-form-for-specific-document-library)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, If any one have any other solution plase post

Comment: I am working on office 365, How can I design a form for document library to document along with some metadata field ?

Comment: did u get any answer on the document upload ? Even i am looking for the same kind of requirement