# How to add a coulmn to the upload form of a document library

Tags: document

I have created a new document library in SharePoint 2013 with a column called: "Expiry date". I have a small question as I'm new to SharePoint: How can I add this newly created column to the upload form:

[image]

Regards,

Ali

Comment: Actually there is a solid misunderstanding here, giving property on Upload form doesn't make sense. Why? Because on opening of this form, the document doesn't exist yet (or haven't been uploaded yet). Since it doesn't exists, how can you set a property of an unexistent item.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using out-of-the-box functionalities. This new column will appear in the following form with all the columns you define on that list (or content type).

If you want to customize the form for uploading documents you should search for a 3rd party application.

Comment: Is there any workwound by modifying the "upload.aspx" or do you have any suggestion for a good tool to do so.

Comment: Apart from doing some custom development, I don't have experience with any other tool. I worked with Nintex Forms but didn't need to include columns for the list in the Upload form. Please, check this thread for doing an On-Prem development, [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/modification-of-layouts-upload-aspx).