# Issue while uploading already existing document in document Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, document-library, 2016, file-upload

I have a scenario where I need to upload a document on a button click, I have used the below URL to upload the document:

```
http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=%7B80B2461E%2DF2EB%2D4272%2D8B2B%2DADD913587A78%7D&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FyourSite%2FShared%20Documents&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsp2016%2Fsites%2Fcalcdemo%2FShared%20Documents%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&IsDlg=1
```

When I check "Overwrite Existing Files" and try to upload the existing files or new files, it will upload without any issue, but when I uncheck the "Overwrite Existing Files" and I try to upload new document which is not already in the document library, the document got uploaded without any issue.

Incase if I upload the already existing document in the library, the page keeps on loading for so long without taking us to Edit metadata page.

Any help would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what you think should happen? You're trying to overwrite a file but don't click the button that allows an overwrite to occur.

What you're seeing does seem to be by design - in that the upload doesn't occur and you just get a page that essentially times out (without an error message, which is useless!)

It looks like you'll need to create your own custom Upload.aspx page if you want it to perform more than the current form.

Here's an answer to a somewhat similar question - [Modification of '_layouts/upload.aspx'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/modification-of-layouts-upload-aspx)

Here's a couple more links that should also help you out;

[How to create custom SP .aspx form](https://yetanothersharepointblog.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/customize-the-sharpoint-upload-page/)

[How to deploy custom forms](https://newsignature.com/articles/deploying-aspx-pages-inside-your-sharepoint-environment/)

Hope that helps.